# The constructor TFSTeamProjectCollection(String) is undefined

Tags: java, tfs

Trying to implement the Java SDK, following the tutorial here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2011/05/16/announcing-a-java-sdk-for-tfs/

I have the libraries imported, but getting a compilation error

```
TFSTeamProjectCollection tpc = 
                new TFSTeamProjectCollection(BASEURL);
```

BASEURL is a string I defined earlier in the code.
The error is: `The constructor TFSTeamProjectCollection(String) is undefined`
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, studying the C# side of things ( see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff731786(v=vs.120).aspx) ) I can't find a constructor that would only take a String argument.

There is only a single argument constructor taking a *Uri*.

In other words: the fact that you your string contains a Url; and that you named it a BASEURL doesn't magically turn it from a String into a URL or URI class object.

Guessing: the ctor wants an argument of type [java.net.URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) which you could probably create with something like `new URL(BASEURL);`  instead of just passing `BASEURL` to that constructor.

The thing is: in order to actually understand which constructors that Team Foundation class has; one would need access to the corresponding SDK from Microsoft - which you probably downloaded and and have in place. So, the only thing that you need to do ... read the javadocs!

Comment: Fair enough - I did read the Java docs, and have converted the string to a URI, with the credentials to null. That being said, if you read the blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2011/05/16/announcing-a-java-sdk-for-tfs/ you'll see that they used a string.

Comment: Anyway, glad it worked for you; so feel free to accept my answer. Where, one final comment: that blog is 5 years old. I wouldn't trust it too much. In other words: you better study the javadoc for the classes you intend to use; instead of relying too much on that (obviously outdated) blog example code.

Comment: still not working, but the error isn't present anymore. Thanks for the help though. Will reply if I do figure it out.

Comment: WARN  [main] TFSTeamProjectCollection - Error getting data provider - 404'd endpoint... trying to figure out what's wrong with my URL (if there is anything wrong with it)

Comment: Thanks for the help - got it. You're right, guess you can't trust an old blog.

Comment: Well, at least your class is compiling then; and code is talking to that URL. So probably you just need some massaging on the URL content itself; or you might have to play around with the various constructors that java.net.URL has.